# Efficient use of POSIX shared memory in a c++ program

Tags: c++, c, linux, posix, shared-memory

I'm using shared memory based on POSIX API on a linux machine to communicate between multiple MPI process.  I have a working solution but I want to know how to make efficient use of the shared memory space for large data.

I have a machine with 64GB shared memory limit and it might happen that I have to write data > 64GB into this space, but these are smaller chunks of 1-2GB.

What I want to know is this:

- How can I really delete the memory occupied by my 1-2GB chunk as soon as it's purpose is served and I don't want that data anymore?

I'm using shm_unlink() but it doesn't seem to clear space in /dev/shm/

Please help!

Comment: In unix you can remove file, but it will still exists until exist at least one descriptor that point to it. So you sure that all processes that use shmem call `close`?

Comment: Yes I do, I guess you meant shm_unlink() on all processes(?)

Comment: Plus, do you think about usage of hugepages ? Split your GB of memory to 4K pages and manage them require a lot of efforts.

Comment: >you meant shm_unlink() on all processes NO, shm_unlink remove name, not file, its like inode vs file. you need call close for file

Comment: Yes, I do both unlink and close.

Comment: So if you run your programs, then programs create/close/unlink files, does lsof /dev/shm report that your program used /dev/shm or it doesn't report?

Comment: this is what's bothering me, when i call unlink on all processes and release the file, ls /dev/shm/ reports empty, but when check for disk usage df -h it reports memory usage!

Comment: It is normal situation, when do open, unlink, and not call close.

Comment: You mean close the file descriptor right? I do that :(

Comment: And I ask again, is output of `lsof /dev/shm` empty?

Comment: Yes it is empty, but still the size is reported by df

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93350/discussion-between-mgr-and-user1034749).

Comment: Btw, is there an order to follow when unlinking, should i unlink first and then close the file descriptor?  Right now I first close the file descriptor and then unlink.

Answer (score 0):

From the sum_unlink description in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/shm_unlink.html
it seems that the memory removal may be actually postponed, read below:

If one or more references to the shared memory object exist when the object is unlinked, the name shall be removed before shm_unlink() returns, but the removal of the memory object contents shall be postponed until all open and map references to the shared memory object have been removed.

I hope this help.